Native file open dialog in Windows Ruby
As far as I understand, there are no gems which help to open native file dialogs, so I am interested in writing one, specifically for Windows
I'm stuck at the first step which is getting the CLSID for the file open dialog, I read somewhere that I need to SysAllocString and pass the resulting BSTR to CLSIDFromString
require 'fiddle'
require 'fiddle/import'
require 'fiddle/types'

include Fiddle
include Fiddle::CParser

clsid = "{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}\0".encode 'UTF-16' # <= must be WCHAR according to winapi specs
clsidptr = Pointer[clsid]

oleaut_dll = Fiddle.dlopen 'OleAut32'
sysallocstring = Function.new oleaut_dll['SysAllocString'], [parse_ctype('const char* string')], parse_ctype('char* bstr')
bstr = sysallocstring.call(clsid) # <= the string here is 0 length which should not be the case
p bstr.to_s

ole_dll = Fiddle.dlopen 'Ole32'
clsidfromstring = Function.new ole_dll['CLSIDFromString'], [TYPE_VOIDP, TYPE_VOIDP], TYPE_INT

buf = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
bufptr = Pointer[buf]
value = clsidfromstring.call(clsidptr, bufptr)

begin
  if value == -2_147_221_005
    raise 'CO_E_CLASSSTRING'
  elsif value == -2_147_024_808
    raise 'E_INVALIDARG'
  else
    puts 'NOERROR'
    puts buf
  end
ensure
  sysfreestring = Function.new oleaut_dll['SysFreeString'], [parse_ctype('char* string')], parse_ctype('void')
  sysfreestring.call(bstr)
end

However I've only been getting CO_E_CLASSSTRING, I've tried different encodings and have not found any solution.
Any and all help would be appreciated
To people saying make a GUI in tk, I would prefer to use native dialog boxes

Have you thought about doing it with WIN32OLE instead? You just need an OLE endpoint for the file dialog. Might be much easier that way.

I agree win32ole makes more sense. I found this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Windows-Platform/Openfiledialog.htm although I can't confirm if it works. If you want this to be cross platform in any way then tk or qt is probably a better bet and other than the dependencies far easier to use.

@Casper I was interested in that approach however I didn't understand OLEs enough to properly execute it, could I have a hint as to how I can create an OLE endpoint for the file dialog box?

@engineersmnky I have seen a few code snippets using that MSComDlg.CommonDialog string, however I think it's no longer applicable for more recent versions of Windows (ruby 3.2.3, Win 11), I appreciate the effort!

While searching for a solution to this I found out this is a hard problem in many languages on Windows. MSComDlg.CommonDialog is the easiest, if you can confirm it exists on your target platform. Besides that, with Tk you can do it in a couple of lines. If you can find a solution in VBScript, you could use the COM scripting host to execute a VBScript to open the dialog too, but it can get complicated quickly as there is no native file dialog on VBScript either. So pick your poison.

@Casper This is not at all a hard problem. It just requires that you know C and COM. I'm sure that Ruby can create arrays of pointers and call functions through function pointers. And those are literally the only language-level requirements for COM.

@Zachary isn't LibUI a thing to consider? https://github.com/AndyObtiva/glimmer-dsl-libui would be a big booster

@AlessandroFazzi hi, I was using that library to write an application when I realised that although it uses native UI elements it doesn't have functionality to call on native dialogs such as file open dialogs, which I feel would be more natural than trying to construct a dialog the user might be unfamiliar with

@Zachary I'm sure that open_file was just an example among others, but better safe than sorry: https://github.com/AndyObtiva/glimmer-dsl-libui?tab=readme-ov-file#extra-dialogs I've just sketched it down and it uses native dialog (I'm on macOS though)

@AlessandroFazzi I admit, I did not see that function there, thank you for pointing it out! I tested and it works on Windows, however I think I'm missing out on customisation options such as dialog title and allowed file extensions, I'm not sure if it is feasible in that library, and if it is, what functions need to be called to achieve this customisation

Using ffi, comdlg32.dll, and GetOpenFileName this seems to work and doesn't require OLE:
# Gems needed: ffi, ffi_wide_char

require 'ffi'
require 'ffi_wide_char'

module ComdlgAPI
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'comdlg32'
  ffi_convention :stdcall

  class OPENFILENAME < FFI::Struct
    layout :lStructSize,       :ulong,
           :hwndOwner,         :pointer,
           :hInstance,         :pointer,
           :lpstrFilter,       :pointer,
           :lpstrCustomFilter, :pointer,
           :nMaxCustFilter,    :ulong,
           :nFilterIndex,      :ulong,
           :lpstrFile,         :pointer,
           :nMaxFile,          :ulong,
           :lpstrFileTitle,    :pointer,
           :nMaxFileTitle,     :ulong,
           :lpstrInitialDir,   :pointer,
           :lpstrTitle,        :pointer,
           :Flags,             :ulong,
           :nFileOffset,       :ushort,
           :nFileExtension,    :ushort,
           :lpstrDefExt,       :pointer,
           :lCustData,         :pointer,
           :lpfnHook,          :pointer,
           :lpTemplateName,    :pointer,
           :pvReserved,        :pointer,
           :dwReserved,        :ulong,
           :FlagsEx,           :ulong
  end

  attach_function :GetOpenFileNameW, [OPENFILENAME.by_ref], :bool
end

def open_file_dialog
  ofn = ComdlgAPI::OPENFILENAME.new
  ofn[:lStructSize] = ComdlgAPI::OPENFILENAME.size
  ofn[:lpstrFile]   = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:char, 260 * 2)
  ofn[:nMaxFile]    = 260
  
  # Use UTF-16LE encoding for wide strings
  filters = "All Files\0*.*\0Text Files\0*.TXT\0\0".encode('UTF-16LE')
  ofn[:lpstrFilter] = FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string(filters)
  
  ofn[:nFilterIndex] = 1
  ofn[:Flags] = 0x00000800 | 0x00001000  # OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST

  if ComdlgAPI.GetOpenFileNameW(ofn)
    # Use ffi_wide_char helper to convert
    # memory to UTF-16LE, and then encode as UTF-8
    return FfiWideChar.read_wide_string(ofn[:lpstrFile]).encode('UTF-8')
  else
    return nil
  end
end

if file_path = open_file_dialog
  puts "Selected file: #{file_path}"
else
  puts "No file selected"
end


Awesome! I saw that you used UTF-16LE instead of UTF-16 as I tried, I replaced the encoding I used and it magically works now! As mentioned in the Microsoft page, GetOpenFileName has been superseded by comdlg, but I guess I can be content with this for now, thank you!

This is literally the first sentence from the GetOpenFileNameW documentation: "Starting with Windows Vista, the Open and Save As common dialog boxes have been superseded by the Common Item Dialog. We recommended that you use the Common Item Dialog API instead of these dialog boxes from the Common Dialog Box Library." This implementation is virtually useless if the goal is to make it into a library.

@IInspectable that's true, however this is definitely functional as of now and the deprecation of this method does not appear to be in the foreseeable future. Furthermore, CoCreateInstance which was suggested in Common Item Dialog API requires the macro IID_PPV_ARGS, which I believe is only available at the compile stage in C programs

@Zachary CoCreateInstance instantiates a COM object (identified by rclsid) and returns the requested interface (riid) through the address of a (type-erased) pointer to that interface (ppv). Callers must establish that the pointer type and interface ID agree (e.g., IUnknown*/IID_IUnknown). IID_PPV_ARGS is a convenience macro that expands to the riid and ppv arguments by determining the interface ID from the pointer. It is not a requirement.

Alright, I'll try it out, will drop an answer using CoCreateInstance if I can get it working

@IInspectable after some attempts, I managed to successfully get a pointer to an IFileDialog, however I'm not sure how to cast it into an IFileDialog class in Ruby Fiddle to use the IModalWindow::show method of IFileDialog, your guidance is much appreciated

@Zachary I'm not familiar with Ruby (though the tag wiki gives me the impression that it's going to be as much of a mess as it is with Python). At the binary level, COM interface pointers point to an array of function pointers. Those function pointers represent the public interface. Calls are made by index. Function names (like show()) are a language-level provision. Translating between function names and array indices needs to be done in the programming language. Maybe take some inspiration from win32ole to see how they are doing this.
